# How to reset X-editable fields after save event

Tags: meteor, x-editable

This is a follow-up question to this answer in https://stackoverflow.com/a/15121394/2247553 on which I cannot comment yet due to the reward system at StackOverflow.

My question is, after the collection update has been requested with Meteor, how do I reset the editable back to its original state in case the server rejects the update?

```js
Template.editableTable.rendered = function() {

  $('#myParentTable').editable({
    selector: '.editable-click'
  });

  $('a.editable-click').unbind('save').on('save', function(e, params) {
    MyCollection.update({_id: 'myid'}, {$set: {key: 'val'}}, function(error, docs) {
      if (error) {
        // how do I reset X-editable here?
      }
    });
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

According to  the [FAQ](http://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/faq.html), if the server side validation fails, you should return a non 200 status.

I know this doesn't exactly answer your question. I'm trying to do the same thing, return a success:false status. It does act like an API in a way, so sending back a 200 suggests that everything worked ok, so it updates the value. The request is to update the value, 200 status is for success.

Hope that makes sense. Please comment if you would like clarification.
My code for the error param of the editable function is below...

```js
error: function(response, newValue) {
    var json = false;
    try {
        json = JSON.parse(response.responseText);
    } catch (e) {
        json = false;
    }

    //Bootstrap message is my own thing.
    bootstrapMessage.init('#search_results');
    if(response.status === 500) {
        bootstrapMessage.show_message('There is a server error. Please contact our supoprt team.', 'danger');
    } else {
        if(json){
            bootstrapMessage.show_message(json.message, 'danger');
        }else{
            bootstrapMessage.show_message('Problem saving your change. Please refresh the page and try again or contact our support team', 'danger');
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I understand about the 200 code, however it is Meteor that doesn't support working this way. You need to check an update's result callback to be able to tell if there was an error. The original update call itself will always succeed by design (when working with Meteor).